# How to solve Asp.Net 3.0 Migrating DB issue?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

.net core 3.0
I developed my application with a sql lite database. Now I am trying to migrate my database to MySQL but I am getting this error when I run my code. After running, it fails and does not create the new Database.

**my connection string**

"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost; Database=datingapp; Uid=appuser; Pwd=4^.-:aX;vqU-QebT"
  },

---

**ERROR**

```
    fail: DatingApp.API.Program[0]
          An error occured during migration
    System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 63.
       at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
       at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
       at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
       at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.cs:line 19
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.MySqlDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseMySql(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 mySqlOptionsAction)
       at DatingApp.API.Startup.<ConfigureProductionServices>b__5_0(DbContextOptionsBuilder x) in /Users/josephlyons/DatingApp/DatingApp.API/Startup.cs:line 47
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<AddDbContext>b__0(IServiceProvider p, DbContextOptionsBuilder b)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.DbContextOptionsFactory[TContext](IServiceProvider applicationServiceProvider, Action`2 optionsAction)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<AddCoreServices>b__0(IServiceProvider p)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
       at DatingApp.API.Program.Main(String[] args) in /Users/.../DatingApp/DatingApp.API/Program.cs:line 25
    info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
          Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
    info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
          Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
    info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
          Hosting environment: Production
    info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
          Content root path: /Users/.../DatingApp/DatingApp.API
```

Comment: Hi ly6n, for ease of reading, try wrapping your connection string in backticks ` to make it look like code. Also, is that all the relevant code? Perhaps provide us with a little more context (not too much code, just a bit more). Finally, I would guess the error is this right here: `System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 63.` Your 63rd character is either the space or the colon, so I would guess that is part of the issue

Comment: Is database always been a MySQL database?  Did you rename the database?  What changes did you make since database last worked?

Comment: Come from dotnet and angular course of Mr. Neil, I stuck on migration db and moving to production. Finally fixed by just changing connection string. Uid and pwd doesn't work in my case, so I change to User and Password and it works. You might need to checking the here: https://mysqlconnector.net/connection-options/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your password contains semi colon in that case instead of this

```
Pwd=4^.-:aX;vqU-QebT"
```

Try this and let me know whether this help you or no.

```
Pwd='4^.-:aX;vqU-QebT'"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is meant to be user and password rather than uid and pwd.

Refer to this page [MySQL EF core](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core.html)https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core.html